# How do I compute the sum of a subset of elements in a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, sum

I want to calculate the sum of the elements in a matrix that are divisible by 2. How do I do it? And how do I output the answer in a co-ordinate form?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a matrix `M`, you can find a [logical index](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#bq7egb6-1) (i.e. mask) for where the even elements are by using the [MOD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mod.html) function, which can operate on an entire matrix without needing loops. For entries in the matrix that are even the remainder will be 0 after dividing by 2:

```
index = (mod(M,2) == 0);
```

You can get the row and column indices of these even entries using the function [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/find.html):

```
[rowIndices,colIndices] = find(index);
```

And you can get the sum of the even elements by indexing `M` with the logical mask from above to extract the even entries and using the [SUM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sum.html) function to add them up:

```
evenSum = sum(M(index));
```

Here's an example with a matrix `M` created using the function [MAGIC](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/magic.html):

```
>> M = magic(3)

M =

     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2

>> index = (mod(M,2) == 0)

index =

     1     0     1     %# A matrix the same size as M with
     0     0     0     %#   1 (i.e. "true") where entries of M are even
     1     0     1     %#   and 0 (i.e. "false") elsewhere

>> evenSum = sum(M(index))

evenSum =

    20
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the matrix `M` with only its even values:

`(mod(M,2) == 0).*M`

You can sum it with `sum(M)` or `sum(sum(M))` (not sure what "co-ordinate form" means).

Comment: MATLAB doesn't have a `%` operator. You want [MOD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mod.html). `%` is for making comments.

Comment: @gnovice - thanks, that's what you get for typing too fast :)

Comment: No problem. That's an easy one to forget after having worked with many other languages that do have `%` as an operator.

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudo-code. Pretty much loop through each column for each of the rows.

```
sum = 0
for(i = 0; i < matrix.num_rows; i++) {
  for(j = 0; j < matrix.num_cols; j++) {
    if(matrix[i][j] % 2 == 0)
      sum += matrix[i][j]
  }
}
```

Not sure what you mean by Coordinate form though.

Comment: OP tagged MATLAB as the language. Loops should be avoided, since vectorization is usually much faster. Gnovice's solution can even be pared down to one line: `sum(M(mod(M,2)==0))`

Comment: Oh wow, thanks. I guess I didn't realize that the OP originally tagged it as MATLAB. My mistake.